# ReactJS setting parent state from child state onClick handler

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning ReactJS and I am trying to create a simple Lightbox. I have three components called ThumbnailContainer, Thumbnail and Lightbox. As shown below:

```js
var ThumbnailContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var thumbnails = this.props.thumbnail_data
    var thumbnail_list = thumbnails.map(function(thumbnail){
    console.log(thumbnail);
        return <Thumbnail key={thumbnail.id} post={thumbnail}/>
    });

    return (
        <div id="thumbnail-container"> 
    {thumbnail_list}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var Thumbnail = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        display: false
    };
  },
  openLightbox: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({display: true});
  },
  closeLightbox: function(e){
    this.setState({display: false});
  },
  render: function(){
    var post = this.props.post;
    return (
        <div className="post" onClick={this.openLightbox}>
            <img className="post-image" src={post.image} />
            { this.state.display ? <Lightbox image={post.image} closeHandler={this.closeLightbox}/> : null}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var Lightbox = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var image = this.props.image
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="lightbox-background" onClick={this.props.closeHandler}></div>
            <div className="lightbox-content" onClick={this.props.closeHandler}> <img src={image} /></div>
        </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Opening the Lightbox works fine, but I am having issues with setting state on closing the Lightbox. For some reason, this.setState doesn't actually set the state to false, it is still set to true after setState was called.

Am I missing something here? I have a fiddle with some examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinrogerteng/6g8u55az/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `openLightbox()` method gets called immediately after the `closeLightbox()` call, so the state changes twice: `display` gets set to `false` then back to `true`. This is because you have two `onClick` handlers in there, and they overlap.

The easiest fix is to put `e.stopPropagation()` into your `closeLightbox()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I feel like I should have known that and how event bubbling works. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this overall?

Comment: If you're able to transpile using Babel, you might want to consider using ES6 so you get things like `const` to make your intentions clearer. You might also want to look at the new stateless functional components, because (for example) your `Lightbox` class would fit right in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @TwoStraws Will definitely look into those.